# What is the best code to use for Removing rel=“nofollow” from woocommerce 'add to cart' buttons

Tags: woocommerce

I have found a few versions of code that can be added to remove the nofollow from the 'add to cart' links in woocommerce.

The most recent code I found is:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_args', 'remove_rel', 10, 2 );
function remove_rel( $args, $product ) {
   unset( $args['attributes']['rel'] );
   return $args;
}
```

Will this do the job and where do I put the code?  I believe it needs to be put in the functions.php file but sometimes it mentions it needing to be in a child theme and others don't mention a child theme at all.

Any help would be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This code works with WooCommerce 3.5.3. Add it to the functions.php of whichever theme you are using.